# "using namespace x" inside namespace in header

Tags: c++, namespaces, gotw

If I've understood Raymond Chen correctly, this is dangerous, but I can't work out exactly why.  http://gotw.ca/publications/migrating_to_namespaces.htm

To be clear, this is not about global namespace pollution due to headers injecting entire namespaces into the global scope, and it's notabout the general case of `using namespace xyzzy;` which some regard as harmful however it's used.

**mymodule.h**

```
#include <string>

// using namespace std;  -- this would be dangerous, and we should never do it

namespace MyModule
{
  using namespace std;  // but, why is this dangerous?

  string foo();
}
```

**mymodule.cpp**

```
#include "mymodule.h"

namespace MyModule
{
  using namespace std;

  string foo() 
  {
    return "bar";
  } 
}
```

Comment: The Guru of the Week article is about migrating from pre-standard C++ without namespace `std` - or any namespace - (and where standard headers had an `.h` suffix), to standard C++ with namespace `std` and standard header name. That was a thing requiring caution. The situation you describe is not too comparable and I don't see why you think the conclusion translate well.

Comment: And at the risk of shameless self-promotion, I believe this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46168188/817643) covers similar ground to the situation you laid out in your snippet.

Comment: The danger is the using directive is pulling in anything that happens to be in `std` — *at that point in the translation unit* — into `MyModule`.  If someone includes a standard header file, then includes `mymodule.h` it'd be easy for `std::foo` to collide with `string foo()`.  Or some future C++ standard that adds a new colliding symbol.  To prevent that kind of contamination just have `namespace MyModule { namespace Secret { using namespace std; } }` and then access them by `Secret::string`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica - that's close enough to call a duplicate. Thanks.